# How can I refactor similar asp.net pages into a common class?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, refactoring

I have inherited a legacy system (asp.net vb) which has several (about 6) pairs of similar web pages. I would like to refactor each pair into a common class and keep the differences in their original classes and aspx files. I found that I need some advice.

I tried creating a common class that inherited from System.Web.UI.Page and inheriting from that common class in my pair of similar pages.  That didn't work out well because the aspx controls in the similar pages weren't available to my top-level class. Passing the controls or their values to the common class didn't seem efficient since controls would have to be passed every time a method of the common class was called. Since there are usually more than 30 controls involved, this seemed more confusing than the original situation.

I also tried creating a helper class for the common code. In this case I put the common code in the helper and left all the code that that worked with the aspx controls in the similar pages. I instantiated the helper class from each of the similar pages at run time. What I wound up with are similar pages that are shorter than the originals, but even more similar than they were before - because they do similar things with similar controls. Very unsatisfying!

This seems like it should be a common refactoring situation, but I can't find any guidance.  Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you looked at MasterPage?

Comment: I'm familiar with MasterPage. In fact, these pages all have the same MasterPage, but I don't see how to use it in this case. Are you saying create a Master for each of the similar pairs?  How could I access the common code in the Master?

Comment: Ah!  Got part of it. Put all the common code in the Master, instantiate the Master in the similar pages and call the common methods. But, can I get access to the control values from the MasterPage which has all the logic?

Comment: You could create User Controls and load them onto the pages when needed.